# Postgres Replication Scenario

Tags: postgresql, replication

I trying to implement following scenario using postgres :

Server A :
This server is used for product A production stage

Server B :
This server is used for product B production stage. This B product is extension product of A which applicable for certain country.

I would like to replicate all changes data on A into B (I understand this can be achieved using master-slave replication), but in same time, there is feature so that People on server B can add new record, and this record should not write into A.

Is there any replication scenario using postgres which suit to above scenario ?

Best

Comment: You probably want [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html) of only the product data. Or create a foreign table in Server A that makes the data in Server B available without replication.

Comment: Does the data to be replicated from A into B occupy the same tables that B will write to itself, or are they separate tables such that A's tables are read only from B's perspective?

Comment: @a_horse : Are suggesting a publisher and subscriber scenario ?

Comment: @jjanes : There will be several tables that need to be replicate from A to B. But, any changes that occur in B should be reflected to A.